# PowerShell Rename file name and keep extension

Tags: powershell

I have found code on here which does what I need it to it

```
$files = gci -filter "*.txt" |select fullname
foreach ($file in $files) {
   $filename = $file.fullname
   $newFilename = $filename.Replace(".", " ")
   rename-item $filename $newFilename
}
```

I require the code to change the file name and keep the file extension.  The code above replaces "." with " ". I can code it to rename the file again to add the extension back. Just wanted to see if there was a better way to do it.

Cheers

Comment: What do you want to change the file name to?

Comment: Yep I would like to run the scripts across a folder to rename files by replacing characters. My code will do that but if I want to replace "." It will change the file extension. Just thought I can use $_.basename can't I.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change `'old'` & `'new'` to whatever you want
Remove the `-Whatif` to apply the command.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp\files -Filter *.txt | 
 Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Basename.Replace("old","new") + $_.extension} -WhatIf -Verbose
```

Comment: Cheers just what I thought when I was on the bus and thought of using the basename. Cheers

Comment: If I would want to add a few things to rename, would i just do another line with the same as above, or can I add to the above.

Comment: if you want to add other commands then you need to put them inside a loop  `Foreach-Object`  . you can put each command on a separate line

Comment: Ok I can do that, I keep getting error when trying to use "."," " saying it can not be null. I want to replace . with spaces.

Comment: i just tried on my system and i dont get an error. If it is difficult to post the error in comments just open a new question with the complete command(s) you have along with the error message.

Comment: All seems to be working, change a few things and all is good. Cheers for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already in the directory where you want to rename all the files regardless of their extensions, this should help.

`Dir | foreach {$i=1}{Rename-Item $_ -NewName (('{0:D5}'+$_.Extension) -f $i++)}`

Where the first block after `foreach` works as an initializing block(if you skip it, tha value will start from default value 0), `{0:D5}` stands for first parameter with `0` padded up to 5 spaces. You could also write it like `{0:00000}` but that `D` is just shorter for decimal values. Needless to say, if you don't want any padding just use `{0}`.

P.S.: You will probably need to add the `-recurse` parameter (after `Dir` if you want to rename files in any subfolder of the directory as well. You can also use a `-whatif` parameter at the end of the code to see the preview of the changes.